# Creating Pom.xml file to store your code in local repository

Tags: android

I want to create an Android Application which uses Maven local repository for method call of particular class which imported in my activity. So, for achieving like this we have to store or add projects in Maven Repository after that we have to give a permission to our project to access files from Maven Repository. All of these are done through the **POM.xml** file. Actually **POM.xml** file is responsible for Maven addition and retrieval. And I don't know how to create correct **Pom.xml** file for doing like above explanation. Please suggest me any tutorial or example which demonstrate me step by step creation and access of **POM.xml**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The general mechanism for dependency management is the same, whether you use Android or plain old Java. So, I'd suggest you read a generic Maven tutorial first (there's tons of it on the net, the ones on the project's page are quite decent).

The main difference regarding Android is not with dependency management, it's with deployment. Read more here:

http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/

(keep in mind the name change, and the link to the SonaType article on the GettingStarted page)

You might also want to use this:

http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/

And finally: I'd recommend to try Maven in Android only if you have several projects under your belt with "normal" Android development. **Maven is not a silver a bullet, and may cost you more time initially than it may save**.